# Evaluating hypergeometric function with a vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, vector, vectorization, evaluate

I am using the generalized hypergeometric function in Matlab by calling hypergeom(a,b,z).

This function produces for a = 1 and a = 2, b = 2 and z = 5:

```
>>hypergeom(1,2,5)
29.4826318205153

>>hypergeom(2,2,5)
148.413159102577
```

Now, I want to evaluate the hypergeometric over a vector of a values. So if I enter hypergeom(1:2,2,5) I would expect the output:

```
[29.4826318205153, 148.413159102577]
```

However, when I enter this in Matlab I get:

```
>>hypergeom(1:2,2,5)
-0.25
```

So a single value is returned, for a vector of input values for a. How do I correctly call hypergeom in Matlab so that I get the same lenght of the output vector as the length of the input vector of a?

**EDIT:**
In this specific calculation I am evaluating the so-called Confluent hypergeometric function (solution to Kummer's differential equation, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function). This is the 1F1 function. This means that length(N) = 1 and length(D) = 1.

The standard built-in function hypergeom is the generalized hypergeometric function, which does not allow the computation of hypergeom(1:2,2,5) in the way I want it.

Patrick Mousaw uploaded his Matlab code for the confluent hypergeometric function(https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29766-confluent-hypergeometric-function), which is the version of the hypergeometric function I am using. A slight adaptation to his code, allowing for elementwise multiplication, returns exactly what I want. :)

Comment: `hypergeom` only vectorizes over the third argument. To use several values of the first argument you'll have to use a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific calculation I am evaluating the so-called Confluent hypergeometric function (solution to Kummer's differential equation, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function). This is the 1F1 function. This means that length(N) = 1 and length(D) = 1.

The standard built-in function hypergeom is the generalized hypergeometric function, which does not allow the computation of hypergeom(1:2,2,5) in the way I want it.

Patrick Mousaw uploaded his Matlab code for the confluent hypergeometric function(https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29766-confluent-hypergeometric-function), which is the version of the hypergeometric function I am using. A slight adaptation to his code, allowing for elementwise multiplication, returns exactly what I want. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely familiar with the generalised hypergeometric function, but it seems to me you have the function arguments the other way round, in terms of what is a 'parameter' (in the mathematical sense) and what is an 'input'. From the documentation:

> HYPERGEOM(N, D, Z) is the generalized hypergeometric function F(N, D, Z),
>     also known as the Barnes extended hypergeometric function and denoted by
>     jFk where j = length(N) and k = length(D).   For scalar a, b and c,
>     HYPERGEOM([a,b],c,z) is the Gauss hypergeometric function 2F1(a,b;c;z).

From wikipedia, I see the formula is:

[image]

So, as far as I understand it, this function is a vectorised function of the array Z, for parameter vectors

  <sub>[image]</sub>

and

  <sub>[image]</sub>
. I.e. to evaluate the generalised hypergeometric function for appropriate parameter vectors N and D, such that length(N)=5 and length(D)=2 (i.e. 

  <sub>[image]</sub>
) on a vector 

  <sub>[image]</sub>
, you'll call `hypergeom(N,D,Z)`, and you should get an output vector of M elements out, one for each element of Z.